# Magento filter object

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, filter

I am trying to get the orders from a few conditions:

1) If order status equals 'betaald' OR 'readyforexport'

2) If payment method equals 'banktransfer' AND order status equals 'pending'

I got the first one working but I need the second one to work aswell.

My code:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
->join(
    array('payment' => 'sales/order_payment'),
    'main_table.entity_id=payment.parent_id',
    array('payment_method' => 'payment.method')
)
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addFieldToFilter('status', 'payment.method',
    array(
        array('eq', 'betaald'),
        array('eq', 'readyforexport'),
    ),
    array(
        array('eq', 'banktransfer')
    )
)   
->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array(
'from'     => strtotime('-1 day', time()),
'to'       => time(),
'datetime' => true
))
->load();
```

How should my addFieldToFilter be build?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
$pendingOrders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array('pending','pending_payment')));
$orders = $pendingOrders
->join(
    array('payment' => 'sales/order_payment'),
    'main_table.entity_id=payment.parent_id',
    array('payment_method' => 'payment.method')
)
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addFieldToFilter('status', 'payment.method',
    array(
        array('eq', 'betaald'),
        array('eq', 'readyforexport'),
    ),
    array(
        array('eq', 'banktransfer')
    )
)   
->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array(
'from'     => strtotime('-1 day', time()),
'to'       => time(),
'datetime' => true
))
->load();
```